# Scroll of a list inside a component does not work

Tags: html, angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic4

I create a generic list (a component) to use in all my pages, but the scroll is not working.

The principal page:

```
<ion-header>
<app-generic-menu [leftMenu]="'left-menu'"
                  [rightMenu]="'client-menu'"
                  [isSelectionMode]="isSelectionMode()"
                  [pageTitle]="'Clientes'"
                  [topicReload]="'client-list:reload'"
                  (valueToSearch)="inputShearchBox = $event">
</app-generic-menu>
</ion-header>

<ion-content>
<app-generic-list [array]="arrayClients"
                  [label1Row1]="'id'"
                  [label2Row1]="'social_reason_name'"
                  [label1Row2]="'document'"
                  [pageToGo]="'/new-client'"
                  [icon]="'person'"
                  [pipe]="documentPipe"
                  [selectedObjects]="selectedClients"
                  (selectedObjectsEvent)="selectedClients = $event">
</app-generic-list>
</ion-content>
```

And this is my component (app-generic-list):

```
<ion-list>
<ion-item *ngFor="let x of array; trackBy: trackByFn" (press)="onLongPressObject(x)"
          (tap)="isSelectionMode() ? onLongPressObject(x) : showObject(x)"
          [ngClass]="{'selected-background': selectedObjects.indexOf(x) >= 0}">
    <ion-icon name="checkmark-circle" slot="start" class="floating-icon" style="color: #43A047;"
              *ngIf="selectedObjects.indexOf(x) >= 0"></ion-icon>
    <ion-icon slot="start" name="{{[icon]}}"></ion-icon>
    <ion-grid>
        <ion-row>
            <ion-label>{{x[label1Row1]}} - {{x[label2Row1]}}</ion-label>
        </ion-row>
        <ion-row>
            <p>{{x[label1Row2] | genericPipe : pipe:[]}}</p>
        </ion-row>
    </ion-grid>
</ion-item>
</ion-list>

<ion-fab vertical="bottom" horizontal="end" slot="fixed">
<ion-fab-button [routerLink]="pageToGo" routerDirection="forward">
    <ion-icon name="add"></ion-icon>
</ion-fab-button>
</ion-fab>
```

I have 10 elements in the array, but only 9 appears, and i can't scroll the page, this only happens with the component, with a normal list inside the `ion-content` the scroll works.

There is any config necessary for the scroll works in a child component?

This is how the app looks:
[image]

There is one more item, but i cant scroll.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add margin-bottom to your list to account for the size of the tab section/footer, and you might need to manually add scroll behavior for the ion-content, ref: https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/content#usage

```
<ion-content[scrollY]="true"></ion-content>
```